# How to pass a variable by reference when creating an object in php

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

So I want to extend for example this [RecursiveIterator from the SPL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php) with the function each so i can easily walk over the object/array

```
class it extends RecursiveArrayIterator {
    public function each( $function, $args=array() ){
        $args = (sizeof($args)>0) ? array_merge(array($this),(array)$args) : array($this);
        iterator_apply( $this, $function, $args );
        return $this;
    }
}
//Running it:
$it = new it( &$array );
$it->each( function( $it ){
    $it->offsetSet( $it->key(),  $it->current() + 1 );
    return true;
});
```

Which results in:

> Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in ...

The problem is i can't, or shouldn't, use the reference when creating the object because its depricated. But when iterating over the array/object i want to be able to make changes to it, how can i achieve this without changing the `allow_call_time_pass_reference` to `On`? I'm using wamp with php 5.3.

Have a nice day

[1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php): http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.phpin ...

Comment: Can you use the `each` method when extending `RecursiveArrayIterator`? I was under the impression that you inherited the previous methods, in which case `each` is not one of them, according to: http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/classRecursiveArrayIterator.html

Comment: @Russell: You can not only overwrite but also add methods in derived classes (otherwise there wouldn't be any class with more methods than StdClass, which has 0 methods ;-))

Comment: Sorry, was just a misunderstanding on my part. For some reason I thought he was implementing rather than extending from `RecursiveArrayIterator`. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious but your callback function used with iterator_apply would not work recursively anyway, making the entire exercise a little pointless.

Comment: @salathe you are right in this example it has no use to use RecursiveArrayIterator but that wasn't really the point of my question... and it can still be usefull when you want to you can use the special recursive 'abilities'

Comment: @user338128 apologies for going off-topic.  So, can you explain why you feel that the reference is necessary at all?

Comment: well i'm used to all the array functions in php and i though i'd experiment a little with the new SPL iterators. Basicly i wanted to do `foreach($array as &$item){ ... }` with SPL, it's mainly for educational purposes.

Comment: the real question is how to modify an array with ArrayIterator. And it seems like currently, without call-time pass by reference, ArrayIterator is not designed to modify arrays; it can only modify ArrayObjects. I think this is a design flaw of ArrayIterator and should be fixed in a later version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to change the constructor to take the variable by reference; but that's not possible here, because even if you changed the constructor for your class, you'd still have to call the parent constructor, which doesn't take by reference.

The solution would have to involve changing the signature of `ArrayIterator::__construct` to receive the array by reference.

In principle, you would be able to override the call-time pass-by-reference limitation with `call_user_func_array`, however that doesn't work with internal functions (in this case, `ArrayIterator::__construct`); see [bug #52940](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52940).

This does **not** work:

```
public function __construct(&$array) {
    call_user_func_array('parent::__construct', array(&$array));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an obvious way to achieve this. The `RecursiveArrayIterator` inherits from `ArrayIterator` with the following constructor prototype: `ArrayIterator::__construct($array,
$flags = 0)`

This means the argument is not passed by reference. And if I recall correctly, you are not allowed to change to signature to accept params by-ref.